# How to stop activity from creating everytime when started from other activity?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a multiple activity app. having activity 1.mainactivity
2.mapsactivity. Now I have a navigation drawer i.e when user click on maps 
an intent will be called to map activity. Because of this when the user starts operating in the mapsactivity and onBackpressed he again returns to mainactivity and when he again go to maps the activity starts again. Is there a solution to this problem, How can I run my activity even if navigating to other activity?

"This is a part of mainactivity having nav drawer"

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_maps) {
            // Maps Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AttendanceActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_rider_app) {

       }
```

Comment: try to put your functionallity  of map activity in onstart and onresume instade of oncreate

Comment: But I have checked and my onCreate method is getting called when the activity starts every time, so onresume will also be called everytime.

Answer (score 1):

add this in your Second Activity

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Comment: this is not working, on Clicking back button in mapsactivity the app completely closes.

Comment: dont call super.onBackPressed();

Comment: i did that only and the app completely moves to background.

Comment: have you added these in mapsActivity ?

Comment: Yes I added it in mapsactivity.

Answer (score 0):

first you should handle onBackpressed in mapsactivity. as you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/state-changes#back) onbackpressed will destroy your activity. you can do something like this in your mapsactivity:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: yeah I tried this on but instead instead of going back to main activity it is directly cutting the app to the background.

Comment: you are right it will move the app to background. you can handle it with some static variables, or with [startActivityforResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Answer (score 0):

Override method `onBackPressed()` in your `MapActivity` and replace `super.onBackPressed();` with

`Intent mainActivtyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
mainActivtyIntent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(mainActivtyIntent);`

Comment: Sir, this was working fine but again on back pressing in the main activity it goes to mapsactivity instead of closing .

Comment: If your application has minimum sdk version 16 then try finishAffinity() in Last Activity from where you really want to close Application.
 `@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
         finishAffinity();
    }`

Comment: my min sdk is 21.

Comment: Then you can use it. Try it.